# Bluetooth HC-05 returning raw values to serial Monitor

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, microcontroller

I am trying to connect Bluetooth HC-05 to Arduino but facing the following problem.

This is Arduino code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(19, 18);
char data=0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);         //Sets the data rate in bits per second (baud) for serial data transmission
    Serial.println("Arduino is ready");
    Serial.println("Remember to select Both NL & CR in the serial monitor");

    BTserial.begin(38400);
}
void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available() > 0)  // Send data only when you receive data:
    {
        data = Serial.read();      //Read the incoming data and store it into variable data
        Serial.print(data);        //Print Value inside data in Serial monitor
        Serial.print("\n");        //New line 
        if(data == '1')            //Checks whether value of data is equal to 1
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);  //If value is 1 then LED turns ON
        else if(data == '0')       //Checks whether value of data is equal to 0
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);   //If value is 0 then LED turns OFF
    }
}
```

The out put displayed in the serial monitor is below:

```
    <x⸮x⸮xxx⸮⸮x⸮x⸮x⸮x⸮x⸮x⸮⸮⸮xxx
```

Comment: Wrong baud rate.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a software serial which is used to make any gpio pins as 'Rx and Tx'. Now the data you receive will come to your board through these pins in this case '19 and 18'but you are checking for data from your other Serial. Check for data availability from 'BTserial' like this 'BTserial.available()' and similarly for 'serial.read' too.

Hope this helps.

You can learn more about software serial from this [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial)

Answer (score 0):

Look like wrong baudrate try the following code `BTserial.begin(9600);`

Answer (score 0):

What is the baud rate you are using on Serial Monitor.Select

> 9600 baud rate

on serial monitor